# How configure CORS in pgAdmin4 - Angular2 project

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I make an app on Angular2, and I need to call my database.
I have an error when I use

```
this.httpClient.put('postgresql://localhost:5432/dbtest', this.tableName)
.subscribe(
  () => {
    console.log("check");
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log("error : ", error);
  }
)
```

I got the error which is `Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error`.

I know that I need to specificate the Access-Control-Allow-Origin, but I don't know where to write it and how.

I am using pgAdmin4 for the database and so where do I write the Access Control on it please ?

I already tried to put it with these commands but without success

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *');
```

I can access to a Query Tool but I don't even know if I can write this type of query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't a CORS issue, CORS issues are known, not unknown. 

And CORS issues are depending on your server, not on your database. 

Finally, I'm going to edit your tags to remove Angular, because even though you use Angular, your issue isn't about Angular. I suggest you use the correct tags, corresponding to your server, and not pgadmin.

Comment: Ok, so how can I fix it please, I use bigsql to run postgre, I use pgAdmin4 to créate database, and angular2 to make the app. In which technology can I do something to fix the problema, and what can I do please.

Comment: Do you know what a server is ? It is something that hosts your application, or in your case, something that hosts your API. What are you using to create your endpoints ?

Comment: Yes I know. I am using my localhost

Comment: That makes no sense ... Let me give examples : APIs can be made with NodeJS, Spring (and be hosted on servers such as Tomcat), Go ... But not localhost. But anyways, `'postgresql://localhost:5432/dbtest'` isn't an actual endpoint. Consider changing this URL to call your API, instead of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ok well, I begin to understand. But for the URL, it is my problema, where can I find the one to call to.

Comment: You decide what URL you will use when you create your API. If you have no API, then you can't make HTTP calls.

Comment: ... I don't understand. My API is what I create with Angular or not ? If it is, what I wan't to call is something who store my database to get back the data. Am I completely fool thinking like I think ? Is that not the right way ?

Comment: I won't say fool, only beginner. Angular is your front-end, you need a back-end. Are you starting development ?

Comment: Well ... I won't say that I am at the fourth year of an engineering school because I will probably take for a really big noob ...

Comment: All what you say, i almost know it, I just have problema to represent it in my head

Comment: Hey, still in school, meaning you still have to learn ! I'm making you an answer to explain it a bit.

Comment: (Are you french by the way ?)

Comment: Thanks, yes I am, my English is as bad as that ?

Comment: Non très bien ,mais je peux te répondre en français, ça sera plus compréhensible !

Comment: Super merci, du coup pour t4expliquer, je connais à peu près tout ça juste Angular je m'y suis mit il y a 2 semaines et le système d'API pour moi est assez abstrait, en plus là je voudrais juste aller chercher des donnés dans ma base de données comme dans le tuto d'angular avec firebase mais cette fois ci vers pgAdmin, c'est possible ?

Comment: Ok alors je t'explique ça, et je connais pas PGAdmin, mais ça m'a l'air d'être un outil de gestion de BDD, donc j'ai envie de te dire que non. Pourquoi pas utiliser Firebase directement ?

Comment: Je doit faire le projet pour une entreprise qui me demande d'utiliser postgreSQL, j'ai donc installé pgAdmin mais si c'est possible avec autre chose ça me convient tant que c'est postgre

Comment: Okay, t'as des bases en JS ? Java ? .NET ? GoLang ?

Comment: JS et Java oui mais le projet doit être en angular et du coup JS j'ai pas trop envie de l'utiliser sauf si j'ai pas le choix

Comment: Pour ton API tu as le choix en fait, Angular restera en Typescript (qui est de Javascript), mais ton API peut être dans n'importe quel language, donc choisis un language dans lequel tu te sens bien

Comment: Très bien je vais voir comment faire tout ça merci beaucoup pour ton aide, je pense que je vais faire du php je sais comment ça marche pour accéder aux bases de données est-ce que tu penses que je peux faire une api avec ?

Comment: [Visiblement tu peux](https://www.univ-orleans.fr/iut-orleans/informatique/intra/tuto/php/rest2.html), mais comme tu le verras dans me réponse c'est pas le must, il est pas fait pour ça à l'origine.

Comment: Je viens de voir ton post, c'est parfait je vais voir tout ça merci :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider changing this URL to call your API, instead of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an API, with NodeJs and ExpressJS is probably the most easy and powerfull to do.

There is a lot of tutorials like this [one](https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-backend-express/)